# Google Maps on Android Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I know that the similar question have been asked before but none solved has solved mine issue, i have been trying to fix this from 3 days but no success.

Recenlty i am following http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_google_maps.htm
but even this is having a problem, my app crashes everytime i launch it on the emulator
Eclipse is not showing any error and
I am sure with the google map key. Along with the tutorial link i m also placing my code :

**Main.java**

```
package com.example.bee;

public class Main extends Activity {
static final LatLng TutorialsPoint = new LatLng(21 , 57);
private GoogleMap googleMap;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.main);
  try { 
        if (googleMap == null) {
           googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().
           findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
        }
     googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
     Marker TP = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().
     position(TutorialsPoint).title("TutorialsPoint"));

  } catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
  }

}
}
```

**main layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

   <fragment
      android:id="@+id/map"
      android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Menifest file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.bee"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

       <uses-permission android:name="com.example.googlemaps.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />

   <uses-sdk
      android:minSdkVersion="19"
      android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
   <permission
      android:name="com.example.googlemaps.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
      android:protectionLevel="signature" />

   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
   <uses-permission         android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

   <uses-feature
      android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
      android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.bee.Main"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="my key"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: What does logcat show when the app crashes? Have you tried running it on a physical device?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add the following `meta-data` tag to your `Manifest` file as well:

```
<meta-data
android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Aslo change this part:

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.example.googlemaps.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<uses-sdk
  android:minSdkVersion="19"
  android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
<permission
  android:name="com.example.googlemaps.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
  android:protectionLevel="signature" />
```

with this:

```
 <uses-sdk
  android:minSdkVersion="19"
  android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
 <uses-permission android:name="com.example.bee.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
 <permission
  android:name="com.example.bee.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
  android:protectionLevel="signature" />
```

You had to change the package in those permissions to your package.

And try to follow the following blog post I wrote on this topic:

[Google Maps API V2 Guide](http://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=435)

Maybe you will have a better luck : )

Comment: @ Emil Adz,  i 've made the changes you sugggested, and also visited the blog, followed your code there, but on both attempts when i launch the app, a white background activity appears with the following message "Google Play services, which some of your applications rely on, is not supported by your device"

Comment: are you testing on a real device?